# Whats the smallest way to say this:

Tags: javascript

What is the most elegant way to say this in JS?:

```
search_keyword = search_keyword.toLowerCase();
search_keyword = search_keyword.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
search_keyword = search_keyword.replace(' and ', '&all=');
search_keyword = search_keyword.replace(' or ', '&any=');
search_keyword = search_keyword.replace(' ', '&all=');
search_keyword = '&all=' + search_keyword;
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just chain these:

```
search_keyword = '&all=' + search_keyword.toLowerCase()
.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
.replace(' and ', '&all=')
.replace(' or ', '&any=')
.replace(' ', '&all=');
```